# Does a regular pair of elements in a noetherian domain remain regular if their order is switched?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Recall that in a commutative ring $A$ an ordered pair of elements (a,b) is said to form a regular sequence if the ideal $\langle a,b\rangle $ is strictly included in $A$ ,if  $a$ is not a zero-divisor in $A$ and if the class of $b$ is not a zero-divisor of $A/\langle a\rangle$.
A friend of mine has asked me if in that case we can conclude that $\langle b,a\rangle $ is also  a regular sequence *under the assumption that $A$ is  a noetherian domain*.
The answer is known to be yes for a *local* noetherian ring $A$, even it is not a domain

[Since I couldn't answer his question, I suggested to my friend that he ask here but he prefers that I do that]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only part to be shown is that $a$ is not a zero-divisor on $A/(b)$. Consider some $s\in A$ such that $as\in(b)$, say $as=bt$. Since $b$ is not a zero-divisor on $A/(a)$, we conclude that $t$ maps to zero in $A/(a)$, i.e., $t=au$. Since $A$ is a domain, it follows that $s=bu$, so $s$ maps to zero in $A/(b)$.

Comment:  Strange, my friend ( a great algebraist who definitely knows what a quotient ring is!) told me he knew a counter-example due to Dieudonné in the case $A$ was a non-noetherian domain. He must have misremembered. Anyway your answer is obviously correct and optimal: thanks a lot.

Comment: According to Matsumura, there is an example by Dieudonne' in nagoya math j.  1966, pp. 355-356, where A is non noetherian and local but not a domain.

Comment: Why is this the only part to be shown?  We also need to show that $b$ is not a zero-divisor on $A$.  That, it seems to me, is the hard part.

Comment: Matsumura also gives a simple example with three elements (a,b,c) in a noetherian ufd A, but A/(a) is not a domain.

Comment: Steven, that bothered me too, but it seems A is a domain by hypothesis, so there is no zero divisor.

Comment: For a non-noetherian counterexample, start with a field, adjoin two elements $a,b$ and infinitely many elements $x_i$.  Set $x_i=ax_{i+1}$ an set $bx_i=0$.  I think this will work.

Comment: Roy Smith:  Ah.  You're right.

Comment: Update: I just phoned my friend to tell him about a-fortiori's solution. He is very happy and told me he would stop looking for counterexamples...